# E: Package 'python3-setuptools' has no installation candidate

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, kali-linux

When i tried to install setup-tools for python3 then it shows this error.
Command-

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

I've got the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to upgrade your system, may be the issue can be solved.

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
```

> Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   python3-setuptools is already the newest version (41.2.0-1). 
>   python3-setuptools set to manually installed. 
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I am using latest version of Kali. Try upgrading your system.